# What is the use of ".children" property in Firebase Realtime Database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone tell me what is the use of ".children" property in Realtime Database rules. I have been searching but I'm unable to find any documentation for the feature. You can see ".children" in auto complete when you type "root" in the rules editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.children` is not (yet) being documented; see for yourself [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#root).

would assume, that it may refer to the *direct* children of a node -

just alike `.child` does, but more than one child node.

one could most likely pass an array of child nodes:

```
"root.children(['users', 'locations'])" {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It would have been nice some actual documentation was available. I'm currently writing some rules and find the lack of loops somewhat limiting. .children seemed like a useful feature which could simplify my work.

Comment: @harsh989 simply try it out (or report a problem with the missing documention, as any page there has a "report a problem" button). if it works, please accept my answer. that array syntax is quite the default, whenever the plural form is being used.